# How to bind a dependency property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a user control in which I have defined a dependency property in its code-behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDependencyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   "MyDependencyProperty", typeof(MyType), typeof(MyView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public MyType MyDependencyProperty
{
   get
   {
      return (MyType)GetValue(MyDependencyPropertyProperty);
   }
   set
   {
      SetValue(MyDependencyPropertyProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Now I want to bind this dependecy property in my view, to a property in my view model, something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Myproject.Views.MyViewView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="1000"
             **MyDependencyPropertyProperty {Binding MyPropetyInViewModel}**
             Name="MyView">
```

This code is to give an idea about what I would like, to use the dependency property to set the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would set the dependency property, where you use your `UserControl`.

```
<MyViewView MyDependencyPropertyProperty="{Binding MyPropetyInViewModel}" />
```

If you really want to do that in the control itself, you could create a style to set the value.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Myproject.Views.MyViewView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myproject.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="1000"
             Name="MyView">
   <UserControl.Style>
      <Style>
         <Setter Property="local:MyViewView.MyDependencyPropertyProperty" Value="{Binding MyPropetyInViewModel}"/>
      </Style>
   </UserControl.Style>
   <!-- ...other markup -->
</UserControl>
```